# Display ASP.NET page inside Flash App

Tags: asp.net, flash, iframe, frame

I have a ASP.NET web app consisting of a few forms which have to be displayed in a certain scenario inside of a flash app, other times displayed as part of a HTML frame.

Is there any functionality within flash that would either act similar to HTML IFrame or be able to render HTML/JavaScript I pass as a string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your Flash app is run in browser (without AIR or a 3rd party exe type of wrapper), from what I've seen you're better off either:

1 - Opening up the form(s) from Flash into a new, HTML based window, either via:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://yourpage"), "_blank");
```

or External interface triggering a JavaScript function to open a new window, which likely would give you more control of the window size. If interested in this method, [this is a good read](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/create-pop-browser-windows-flash.html).

2 - Recreating the forms within Flash itself, which means you'd maintain copies of the forms in two places, and may need to alter your ASP pages to act more like webservices.

Flash TextFields do have an Htmltext property, but last I checked there seemed to be no use of it other than rudimentary formatting of text, according to HTML version 1.0 standards.